# Obfuscation file (.conf.obf extension) for Tivoli Access manager

Tags: xslt, obfuscation, ibm-datapower, tivoli, tivoli-identity-manager

Can anyone help me on, how can we convert .conf file to obfuscated file .conf.obf extension? Any tool or link where I can find the steps for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use /opt/PolicyDirector/sbin/pdconf binary.  It has an option to obfuscate values within a config file.  Run the pdconf binary to see the options.  Essentially it would look something like this:

```
/opt/PolicyDirector/sbin/pdconf -f /opt/whatever.conf setentry -obfuscate stanza entry value
```